# Site Collection Web Analytics reports numbers are incorrect

Tags: search, fast-search, statistics

We are experiencing problems with the reports from the site collection web analytics. We use SharePoint Server with FAST search on a public facing web site. Our SharePoint solution is only used for searching, not displaying content or anything else.

We are using webtrends to log visits and searches on the site. The difference between webtrends and the SharePoint reports are huge regarding the query count.

We have about seven thousand visitors each day, give or take. The reports from SharePoint and Webtrends are somewhat equal here. When it comes to the number of queries, SharePoint is underreporting by a lot.

When looking through the logs, on a couple of days the Site Collection Web Analytics reports (SCWA) reported not more than a few queries the whole day. Webtrends reported several thousand queries for the same day.

We're not saying that the we are certain the Webtrends numbers are 100% correct, but we are pretty sure that the SCWA numbers are far off. For a search site with 7k unique visitors, we would expect at least 7k daily queries.

What's pretty weird is that we can see some queries being logged and the numbers are varying day by day. The total number is only a small percent of the total though.

How can we start resolving this problem? How are SP logging the search queries? We have not made any changes to the OOTB SCWA-functionality - if that's even possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem or have any more information you can add to the question?

Comment: Nope. We are looking into getting help from MS support.

Comment: Did you get that help from MS?

Comment: This is probably stupid, but what user agents are reported by SCWA and Webtrends?

Answer (score 2):

The usage data comes from a SQL Database named WSS_UsageApplication. When you provisioned web analytics, a reporting database was created. You can query this database safely from my understanding because it was designed for reporting. It is an aggregation of data from WSS_UsageApplication. Some query data is in a table named WAQueryTextAggregationByDate.

My guess is that FAST might be doing something different than standard SharePoint Search and therefore might not be tracked correctly. I haven't tested that theory. You might also find some good diagnostic infomration in the IIS Logs.